# Use of lambda during member variable initialization within class declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

For readability, I like to initial member variables within class declaration. I am also intrigued by used of lambda during such initialization ( see snippet). My question is what are the advantages or disadvantages of using such lambda functions in the declaration over member functions.

```
class foo
{
   private:
      int index_ = 5;
      int value_   = [](int index)
                     {
                         int result = 0;
                         for( int i = 0;i <index; i++)
                            result += i;
                         return result;                             
                     }(index_ );

};
```

Edited:
  As bar::bar(int index) :index_(index) {} is more optimized than bar::bar(int index)  {index_ = index;}, whether the above code performs better or it just the readability.

Comment: it's broken in gcc in certain situations, so that's one thing.  It was reported in a question on SO yesterday.  https://godbolt.org/g/o4oPfa  But in general, this is a question of taste, which is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: @GillBates How does it coincide with this topic?